# How to make an attendance form

Tags: views

I specifically hope views can solve my issue.

My views will display the list of students in a specific class and in front of each student's name, I will like to have a button to select whether a student is present or not.

Since this page will be accessed daily(monday-friday), it needs to reset to default everyday but the record must be saved in d database so that we can send the total number of days a student is present in school.

I have tried flag but the issue with the approach is that u can either flag or unflag a user which doesn't allow for daily flaggings.

Could you give me any hint as to what next to try? Do I need to write a module for this?

Comment: I know the answer, but I gotta go. I'll get back to you later.

Comment: I think you need a custom module with a table that records the uid, date and a bool for present or not. This way you can record every entry seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules needed: [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), Rules Scheduler (comes bundled with rules)

1. Create a user flag
2. Add an **integer** field to your user fields. Ex: Attendance (this will keep track of the # of days attended)
3. Create a new Rule

React on A user has been flagged

Actions: Set a data value >> flagged-user:field-user-attendance >> OFFSET : 1

> So this will +1 your field every time the user is flagged.

4. in Rules add a new component.

Component: Rule >> **Data Type:** User >> **Label:** att >> **Machine Name:** att >>

Actions: Unflag a user >> **USER:** att >> **USER ON WHOSE BEHALF TO FLAG:** att >> Skip permission check

5. Go back to your Rule and add action of Schedule Rule Component

Select your component >> **SCHEDULED EVALUATION DATE**: +5 hours >> Identifier: `[flagged-user:name] will be auto unflaged soon` >> ATT: flagged-user

> so in 5 hours all users that are flagged will be auto unflagged. (this auto resets them for you, so you are ready to flag the next day)

## Update

> [A good solution but the date really needs to get recorded as well – J. Reynolds](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188640/how-to-make-an-attendance-form/188663#comment-228727)

Challenge accepted.

In users add a field called "Date Attended" type:text field. In settings Change **number of values: Unlimited**

[image]

In your rule, add Action: Add an item to a list >> flagged-user:field-date-attended >> ITEM TO ADD: click on switch to direct input mode and then put [site:current-date] >> Append item to the end.

> This will auto add a new term with a timestamp when you flag a user/student.
>
> [image]

You can then use the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module if you want to hide this from users so they cant see it and/or edit it.

PS: I think you might know this already, but just in case. To add a flag link to your view, first you need to add a RELATIONSHIP of flag to your view. Then the flag link option will be available to add as a field in fields.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: The Scheduled rule will be triggered in the next cron run.

Comment: A good solution but the date really needs to get recorded as well

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but how about adding a Field Collection to the User entity with date and a bool for attendance. Then instead of updating the count field on the User the Rule will create a new instance of the field collection for the User. That way every single instance of attendance is recorded. But I don;t know if Rules can add a new instance of a field collection.

Comment: @J.Reynolds solved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. but under 5, SCHEDULED EVALUATION DATE, What will be the data selector please?

Comment: actually switch back to direct input mode. Erase/delete the default value, ex: `2016-01-31 07:43:41` and type `+5 hours`

Comment: I actually set this to +10 seconds so as to see the views page reset after 10 seconds but nothing is happening. Do you think i just did something wrong?

Comment: Sorry I did not test that part, on paper it should work. Give me a few mins to test it out.

Comment: Updated Step 4. on your component unflagin use **USER ON WHOSE BEHALF TO FLAG:** att

Comment: If you're testing it, you need to run crun. As the scheduled rule will not be triggered until cron runs. `admin/config/system/cron`

Comment: Thank you. It did work exactly as i wanted. How did u know all these rule config? All from the rules documentation page on drupal?

Comment: You're welcome. I learned from countless of hours spent watching video tutorials and experimenting trial and error and reading Q&As here. Learning Rules can be very daunting, but once it clicks and you get it, you discover that Rules is incredible powerful. The update part, I've never done that before. I had to experiment and got it to work. I learned something new from answering your question.