# Views show empty fields

Tags: views, nodes

How to use Views to list all empty apartments, which do not have any tenant? So basically I have two content type: Apartment and Tenant as below.

Apartment content type:

- Room
- Tenant (entity reference to Tenant content type)

Tenant content type:

- Name
- Phone

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: In the fields, i have content type: room, content type: referent to tenant, Views conditional if tenant is empty then output apartment and content: title.  In filter criteria, I have content:type apartment checked. So they list all the empty room and also room has tenant. What i want is just empty room to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple in Filter Criteria, click add and add your entity reference field.

[image]

When you are adding your field, for **Operator**, select `Is Empty (Null)`

Drupal 8 Example:

[image]

Drupal 7 Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You are right, it is so simple. Why didn't I think about it? :D. Anyways, may I ask you another question? Is there anyway to use Views to keep a record of any change of tenant field in the Apartment content type? Because when tenant moves out and others move in a apartment, I want to keep a record of that. I have tried Track field changes, but it prints out only one change at a time.

Comment: You're welcome @Tony. If my answer solved your problem, which sounds like it, you can accept the answer by clicking on the check ✅, and a vote up, if you haven't already, would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I have already voted for it. If you have an answer or a suggestion for my question below, i appreciate it.

Comment: @Tony to answer your comment Question. If you're on Drupal 7, you can use the Rules module to store the value(s) of your tenant field in another field when your node is saved and if your value has changed. Else, if you're on Drupal 8, you will have to do this programmatically by creating a small custom module to do this for you.

Comment: So your storage field is a field of unlimited values, and each time your entity reference field changes, you store the value that was there in here, then all you gotta do is add this field to views.

Comment: @Tony the concept is somewhat similar to my answer to this Q [How to make an attendance-form](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188640/how-to-make-an-attendance-form/188663#188663)

Comment: @Tony if you need help with that, you can always ask a new question about that in this site.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try your suggestion now. :)

Comment: So@No Sssweat. I created a field called previous tenant under the tenant field and my rules are like this, and it does not work.

Comment: { "rules_tenant_records" : {
    "LABEL" : "Tenant records",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update--apartment" : { "bundle" : "apartment" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node-unchanged:field-tenant" ], "field" : "field_tenant" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "node:field-previous-tenant" ],
          "value" : { "value" : [ "[node:field-tenant]" ] }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: and... did it work as expected? if not [ask a new question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) regarding that, cheers!

Comment: No, it did not work as expected.