# count entityreference multivalue field conicidences (make an attendance form)

Tags: 7, entities, views

This question is similar to this one [How to make an attendance form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188640/how-to-make-an-attendance-form), but i solved by [entity refrence view widget module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget), saving date in a node, and having a field entityreference user relation with unlimited values. Now i have a views table of nodes like:
[image]

and now i can not sum how many times a user entityreference appears, ofcourse at the bottom i need to have: John=3, Mary=2, Pete=2
I tryed [views aggregartor plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) with no luck, please make some suggestions how to achive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. This is what I did. In order to not make heavy loads i enebleded Entity Construction Kit (eck) module, then by rules i added an entity (instead of a node) for every user entity reference value, within two columns, one for user name, and one for date in attendance. Now I can have a view (of entities) with two exposed filter on dates (beginning and ending dates) Then I override my views table tpl view with the following code. It displays a 2 column table, first: username, second: number of days that user has attendance.  the following code assumes that username is second field on your view ($fieldloop == 2 ). code:

```
<?php $names = array(); ?>
```

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row_count => $row): ?>
   <?php $fieldloop = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>          
    <?php if ($fieldloop == 2 ) {$names[] = strip_tags($content);} ?> 
    <?php $fieldloop = $fieldloop + 1; ?>          
    <?php endforeach; ?>              
<?php endforeach; ?>

  <?php $attendances = (array_count_values($names)); ?>
<body>
<table>
<tr><th>Alumno</th><th># dias</th></tr>
<?php foreach ($attendances as $attendance => $value) : {
?><tr><td>  <?php print $attendance ; ?></td>
<td> <?php print $value; ?></td></tr>
<?php } endforeach; ?> 
</table>
</body>
```